# Detect queried field via greatest()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-table

I'm using the mysql [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function to select the highest integer value from either column (apples or peaches).

```
+----+------------------+
| id | apples | peaches |
+----+------------------+
|  1 |    8   |    4    |
|  2 |    2   |    6    |
|  3 |    3   |    9    |
|  4 |    7   |    2    |
|  5 |    4   |    4    |
+----+------------------+
```

Using `$result = "SELECT GREATEST(apples, peaches) FROM table";` and `echo $result`, I get:

```
8
6
9
7
```

Next to each value, I want to echo the corresponding fruit name and a fruit icon. How can I achieve the image below via the MYSQL query?

[image]

Also, notice that equal values aren't displayed by the `GREATEST()` function. Is there a way to display the equal value as well?

Comment: Do you only have 2 columns or is this a simplified example?

Comment: Yes I need to compare just 2 columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
IF(apples >= peaches, apples, peaches) AS quantity,
IF(apples >= peaches, 'apples', 'peaches') AS fruit
FROM ...
```

or, if you don't want apples to be the default on equal and want to know when both fruits are equally represented:

```
SELECT 
IF(apples >= peaches, apples, peaches) AS quantity,
CASE WHEN apples > peaches THEN 'apples' WHEN peaches > apples THEN 'apples' ELSE 'both' END AS fruit
FROM ...
```

Comment: thanks your code works! I wanted to preserve the `greatest()` function so I implement your code into this working query `SELECT GREATEST(apples, peaches) as quantity, CASE WHEN apples > peaches THEN 'apples' WHEN peaches > apples THEN 'peaches' ELSE 'both' END AS fruit FROM ...`